# Any way to boost Wi-Fi on Nexus 7?

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-7

My Nexus 7 seems to have poorer Wi-Fi reception than my iPad (1st generation). At home it is always able to reach the router, so not an issue. Occasionally when I am out the iPad will have reception when the Nexus 7 doesn't.

I was looking inside the back cover, and it appears there are a few antenna built into the cover. I am curious if the Wi-Fi antena is in the back cover, and if there is some way I could boost it by attaching an external perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iFixit has a Teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus-7-Teardown/9623/1) that shows the Wi-Fi antenna is on the back. Interestingly, when I took it off and looked I saw that it was nicely labeled too. Also, the Wi-Fi reception seems much better after reattaching the cover. Maybe my Antenna wasn't connected very well.

It appears a simple mod could be done to attach an external Wi-Fi antenna if I needed to do that. A mod may be in my future.